# Mongodb aggregation stage $match results with timeout error

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

There are around 9000 users in users_table and the user with the highest order count has around 300 orders.

When I query with the code below everything works just fine until the `$match` stage. It takes more than 20 secs so the query is resulted with timeout error. I know I can increase the time to get rid of that error but I want to know WHY a simple `$match` stage takes very long time?

```
db.getCollection('users_table').aggregate([
{
// user.id field is related to order.user_id field 
  '$lookup': {
    'from': 'orders_table',
    'localField': 'id',
    'foreignField': 'user_id',
    'as': 'orders'
  }
},
{
// I keep user.id and the delivered orders
  '$project': {
    'id': 1,
    'filtered_orders': {
      '$filter': {
        'input': '$orders',
        'as': 'order',
        'cond': {'$eq':['$$order.status', 'delivered']}
      }
    }
  }
},
{
// get rid of _id and get delivered order count as well as user.id
  '$project': {
    '_id': 0,
    'id': 1,
    'order_count': {'$size': '$filtered_orders'}
  }
},
{
// get order_count field between 200 and 350
  '$match': {
    'order_count' : {'$gte': 200, '$lte': 350}
  }
}
])
```

Comment: did you try adding indexes on user_id and id?

Comment: No I didn't because I don't know how to do it yet :)

Comment: db.users_table.createIndex( { id: 1 }, { background: true } ) db.orders_table.createIndex( { user_id: 1 }, { background: true } )

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Comment: Creating indexes on those fields solved the problem. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding indexes

```
db.users_table.createIndex( { id: 1 }, { background: true } )
db.orders_table.createIndex( { user_id: 1 }, { background: true } )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query. also make sure 'status'  in orders_table is indexed

```js
db.getCollection('orders_table').aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'status' : 'delivered'
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      _id:'$user_id',
      order_count: { $sum: 1 }
      user_id:'$user_id',
    }
  },
  {
    '$match': {
      'order_count' : {'$gte': 200, '$lte': 350}
    }
  },
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this solution. This way I cannot get the users whose order count is zero. Also, I don't really know anything about indexing :/ I will try to learn and use it. Thanks.

Comment: in you question your last match remove all users that have less then 200. if you want all users dont do the last match

Comment: I don't want all the users. The $match limitations 200 and 350 are just random numbers for this question (Your solution works with them by the way). However if I want to get users with order count between 0 and 25 ({'$gte': 0, '$lte': 25}) your query will not include the users with 0 order count.